# Increase the resolution of the screenshot in phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

The final images rendered by phantomJS are blurry i.e., the fonts in the screenshot are blurry too. I researched through various stackoverflow questions but could not find the accurate answer. Is there any way to increase picture quality of the phantomJS to reduce/eliminate blurriness?

I use windows and the JS code:

```
  var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('webpage.html', function () {
  page.render('webpage.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: @Vaviloff - I have added the code. Is this what you were expecting? I tried settimeout, setinterval.. I dnt think they made a difference.

Comment: And can you show a sample of a blurry screenshot made by this script?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be you are rendering the screenshoot with the default view port. Increasing the view port will give you better quality. try this.

```
page.set('viewportSize', {
           width: 2048,
           height: 1024
          });
```